# Convert array of promises to chain in React

Tags: reactjs

I've seen a number of posts covering similar chaining questions, but I'm trying to understand what I'm specifically missing.

Ultimately, I want to make an API call, then make a second based on the results of the first.  To do so, of course, I need to have the results, not just a promise to get them before I make the chained call.  I started from an example that does not have the chaining dependency:

```
export const FetchUserSync = () => {
    return Promise.all([
        fetchUsers(),
        fetchPosts()
    ]).then(([user, posts]) => {
        return { user, posts };
    });
    
    function fetchUsers()...

    function fetchPosts()...
}
```

When I call it, the data comes back and state values are set.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dataPromise.then(data => {
        setUser(data.user);
        setPosts(data.posts);
    });
```

Attempting to change the first code so the second call will wait for the first to complete, I get results in the function (`console.log` or setting `debbugger` shows populated objects for user and posts exist), but the useEffect's calling function shows the result to be undefined.

```
export const FetchUserSync = () => {
    return Promise.all([fetchUsers()])
        .then(([user]) => {
            Promise.all([user, fetchPosts()]) 
                .then(([user, posts]) => {
                    return { user, posts }
                })
        });
        
        function fetchUsers()...
    
        function fetchPosts()...
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to make the second idea work or should I just scrap it and go with one of the other answers?

Comment: Does an explicit chaining work for you? Like `fetchUsers().then(user => fetchPosts(user)).then((posts) => console.log(posts))`

Comment: @barny  Thanks, but scrap is a common US idiom for throwing away an idea.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you wouldn't want to use `Promise.all`.

Since both `fetchUsers` and `fetchPosts` both return promises already, wrapping singular calls with Promises for `fetchUser` and `fetchPosts` is an anti-pattern.

Additionally, consider using async/await since they avoid deeply nested chains of data.

Here's what you could do:

```js
export const FetchUserSync = async () => {
  const users = await fetchUsers();
  const posts = await fetchPosts();

  function fetchUsers() { ... }
  function fetchPosts() { ... }

  return { users, posts }
}
```

The code will make a request for users, then once users is received, it will make another call for posts.

Consider reading more on async/await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Your code will wait until `fetchUsers` will be resolved and then make `fetchPosts`. But those fetches independent So `Promise.all` more quickly. For example, if `fetchUsers` is resolved by time `a` ms, and `fetchPosts` is resolved by time `b` ms, async/await will be resolved `a+b` ms. In the same time `Promise.all` will be resolved Math.max(a,b) ms.

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Yeah you're right in your case, but I'm pretty sure OP wants this effect: "Attempting to change the first code so the second call will wait for the first to complete". In some cases, you'll need the result of the first call to make the second call. OP's current code does fetch the code simultaneously but I think he's attempting to wait for the first call to finish first.

Comment: @KevinBai thanks, I perhaps oversimplified my example but you nailed it.  I want to get to the point where the second call relies on data from the results of the first.

Comment: @KevinBai  I can't even estimate how many (often convoluted) failed attempts I had!  Thanks, again.